# VMWare workstation 6.5 bridged networking stopped working

Tags: networking, troubleshooting, vmware-workstation

I have an XP client running on a Vista host. The client used to have bridged networking working fine, lately it stopped working for no aperant reason. Other kinds of networking works, though.

It seems that the client can't assign itself an address using DHCP. I tried to set up the addresses manually, but it didn't help.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Dumb question, but has your DHCP server run out of assignable addresses?

Answer (score 2):

By sheer coincidence I ran into this last week. What happened was that the Bridged network connector was set to automatically figure out which of my network ports to use for the bridge, and was picking the wrong (disconnected!) one. Forcing it to use the port that was actually connected to a network caused it to work immediately.

Comment: Had this also happen a lot with Linux as the host.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a possible solution. Open your network adapter's properties and click VMware Bridge Protocol.
Now here's the catch. If you try to reinstall it, it tells you it's marked for deletion. Since I'm still getting used to Windows 7 and all it's quirky newness, I simply rebooted the machine then went back into the network adapter's properties and installed VMware Bridge Protocol and started the WMware Agent service.

NOTE:  Make sure you are not running any of your VM's while doing this or you will have problems with your Network adapter trying to find the network.

Basic instructions can be found here:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=1008367&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&dialogID=52180022&stateId=0%200%2052906419

The instructions are basically for Windows XP. Skip the parts about Linux, of course.

If that doesn't work, I've found that rebooting the VM usually fixes it for a little while. It's really weird.